# How to specify multiple platform for a dynamic framework in podfile

Tags: frameworks, cocoapods

I've created a dynamic framework locally to use it in my iOS target and Today app extension target. It's work well.

Now I want to use it in iWatch target but xcode doesn't find my framework on import line.

I think it's because I don't specify watchos platform in podfile for myFramework target but I didn't find how to put 2 platform at the same time in Podfile for one target ?

Here is how my Podfile looks actually:

```
target 'myApp' do
    platform :ios, '9.0'
    app_pods
end

target 'myExtension' do
    platform :ios, '9.0'
    inherit! :search_paths
    main_pods
end

target 'myWatch Extension' do
    platform :watchos, '2.0'
    inherit! :search_paths
    main_pods
end

target 'myFramework' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    main_pods
    target 'myFrameworkTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        testing_pods
    end
end
```